# How to stop backup of SQL Server to other machine?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two machine which have SQL Server (same version) installed, but both machines have different `sa` password.

Now I am making backup program  which allows you take backup any where like pendrive or any hard disk.

I want to restrict all users who can not take backup without `sa` password in any machine

So how can I stop `.bak`  file to restore other machine?

Comment: I have edited the question as per my understanding of your request,please check and let me know if that is what you are trying to ask

Comment: see this for more info on password protected backups:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1108/using-passwords-with-sql-server-database-backup-files/

Comment: yes i want this.but if i restore the db through management studio then?